# Crowbar circuit design: choosing the correct parts

Tags: circuit-design, components, over-voltage-protection

I've designed a crowbar circuit with the aim of protecting my circuit from overvoltage (it cannot exceed 15V) and reverse polarity protection.

Looking online,Ii've found that a good solution for overvoltage is the "crowbar" circuit, and I've designed this:

[image]

This circuit is supposed to protect my circuit from overvoltage and reverse polarity (diode D7.)

The parts that I've picked are supposed to work for the following power needs:

The circuit normally works with 12V input and it will power two devices:

- A low current device (that draws up to 500mA)
- A step down converter (LM2596) that drives a high current LED strip (that draws up to 2A at 5V.)

Here comes the crowbar circuit. As you can see in the image, the netflag marked as +12V-POE powers the low current device, and has a maximum allowed voltage input of 15V, the VIN netflag is the voltage input of the LM2596 and steps down the voltage to 5V, allowing the high current LED strip to be powered.

I have some doubts about the components that I've picked from the JLCPCB library (I need to use their library in order to receive the board assembled and ready to be tested.)

Do you guys think that with those components the crowbar circuit will work without any problems?

Leaving the resistor and capacitor aside, here are the datasheets of the thyristor, fuse and picked diodes:

- [Fuse](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/New-Arrivals_PTTC-Polytronics-Tech-SMD1812P300SLR-24_C495359.html)
- [Zener](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Zener-Diodes_ST-Semtech-MM1Z15_C86235.html)
- [Thyristor](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Thyristors-TRIACs_STMicroelectronics_TN1515-600B-TR_TN1515-600B-TR_C157421.html)
- [Schottky](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Schottky-Barrier-Diodes-SBD_MDD-Microdiode-Electronics-SS34_C8678.html)

Comment: The device you wish to protect - can you link its data sheet please?

Comment: Is the 47n to keep it from turning on too fast?  or to stabillize it vs feedback?

Comment: @Andyaka Here is the device: wesp32.com/files/wESP32-Product-Brief.pdf

Comment: @PeteW the 47n is a simple and effective snubber capacitor

Comment: @Andyaka, any help on that?

Comment: Can you supply a link to the device you wish to protect?

Comment: @Andyaka, here is the device that i wish to protect: wesp32.com/files/wESP32-Product-Brief.pdf

Comment: Do you mean this: https://wesp32.com/files/wESP32-Product-Brief.pdf - note that this is a working link to a device unlike the non-working links you have provided.

Comment: However, there isn't enough information in that document to tell me what the normal current is. I'm no expert on that product so I'll gracefully back away from answering.

Comment: Depending on the properties of D7, there is a chance it could limit the current and prevent the fuse from blowing, or slow it down. The SCR also has a substantial voltage drop after it trips. The two voltage drops together plus whatever current limiting in the supply could be substantial. It may be a good idea to put a capacitor between D7 and F1. The capacitor should be big enough to blow the fuse all on its own. If you don't mind blowing the fuse in the event of reverse polarity, you could just put the diode from F1 to GND so it is reverse biased in normal operation.

Comment: Things have moved on since the 70's and grandpa wants his crowbar circuit circuit back!  Current solutions would be a transzorb and fuse or a p or n chan mosfet with a zener or voltage detector ic to open or short the supply. Note that polyfuses don't really appreciate long term overloads - they tend to go up in flames. SMT ones especially. I can't see what you want to achieve based on the link to the wesp32 - it has its own poe converter and states specifically to use only proper poe power sources.

Comment: @Kartman, what i want is to protect the wesp32 from overvoltage using this crowbar circuit, specifically, the wesp32 has a pin named +V (pin 20) that can accept up to 15V and powers up the buck converter of the board.

Comment: Use a TVS diode like a SMCJ13A-13-F or similar. Does your reverse protection as well. Use a through hole polyfuse if you expect long term overloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace the standard fuse with a PPTC, it will work in <1s safely and be resettable with a power cycle.  These will operate at a component temperature of 125'C which is safe for ceramic and draw low power.  There is no time to trip variation as the trigger is defined by the voltage threshold.

For a more precise threshold, D1 could be replaced by a TL431.

The inductance in the loop must be kept low relative to the ESR as it resembles a high Q series RLC circuit with a natural overshoot. This is not difficult for normally small layouts but may be considered for dry contact step inputs.

### final comments

For a detailed analysis, one needs to know the energy stored in Capacitors in the source and load as the PPTC is charging them up and the driving impedance of supply that may have failed with overvoltage and its max loop current on crowbar.  Also if there is an inductive load, the flyback voltage must be considered too.

This is a tradeoff with the load regulation ripple you can tolerate as defined by the total series ESR / pulsed load dynamic resistance and the stress on the wire junctions of all components including protection devices.   This is beyond the scope of this question.

There is also the question of reliability for the supply, the fuse and the sustainability of operation and the level of transferred overvoltage from outside forces. (e.g. lightning).

This often requires a more comprehensive approach with snubbers , over-voltage absorbers and serial current limiters and depends on the quality of the design specs required.

Comment: You think that PPTC fuse will be ok? https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/2003131817_PTTC-Polytronics-Tech-SMD1812P300SLR-24_C495359.pdf

Comment: Looks fine. The main thing is this part heats up faster than anything else, so it protects your device within the defined limits 50A etc in less than a second.

Comment: Consider that the board pheriperials will draw up to 2.5/3A at full power

Comment: Consider that the SCR has dynamic R of 25mΩ if your supply has a low ESR cap, can it generate > 50A? If so, the SCR is overkill and the PTC is at risk.

Answer (score 1):

The parts you stated is pretty much solid.
But the fuse is the main concern. Using PPTC is not good, considering the PPTC working similar to Thermostat as the heat increase the threshold would reach. And the trip current is more likely to go 2x or more depending on the time to trip.

Use better fuse as such as a very fast-acting ceramic fuse.

And for the crowbar acting, you can use double protection with TVS diode for protection against overvoltage and or Varistor (Metal Oxide Varistor)

Comment: So, you suggest a classic fuse?

Comment: All other components are ok? they might work without any issue?

Comment: classic fuse is better, but not the glass fuse because the glass fuse tends to make a spark when tripping. the current draw you suggest is lower than your component can handle it. As for a fast-acting crowbar, I suggest make it simpler like using TVS diode or MOV or both of them. Because you need to make over-voltage protection. Or you can use the SMPS over-voltage protection design which using Optocoupler that working to turn off the Mosfet, so basically your device Vsource controlled with mosfet.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution looks ok but you can avoid the series diode which drops a \$V_f\$ by using a simple 1N400x connected after the fuse to ground:

[image]

When the wrong polarity is applied, the diode immediately conducts and brings the right-side of the fuse to ground, melting it immediately.

Regarding the crowbar, a Zener diode will certainly do the job but keep in mind that the threshold will be the Zener voltage plus the 1.3-V typical of the gate-cathode voltage which is variable with temperature and production. A more precise circuit would involve a dedicated circuit like the [MC3423](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/motorola/MC3423D.pdf) if some remember the glorious MOT days. A more recent product like the [LTC1696](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc1696.html#product-overview) seems to do the job well also:

[image]